# See top results cProfile

Tags: python, profiling, cprofile

I have a main() function and I am running

```
cProfile.run("main()",sort="cumtime")
```

However, since I have a very large script, I can only see the bottom results and not actually do any profiling. Is there a way to filter for the top bottleneck results only?

Comment: Where do you run that in? Any good IDE (e.g. Spyder) has a profile tab that sorts the result depending on what you need.

Comment: For another (in browser) visualisation use e.g. Snakeviz (https://jiffyclub.github.io/snakeviz/)

Comment: Upvoted: I also face this problem. I run cProfile via the command line and want to see only the top "N" results after sorting by some criteria (e.g. -s tottime). Please let me know if you've found a solution to the same.